# Make the form recheck the ModelView

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a WPF form using a `ModelView`. This `ModelView` has a `List` of items. The problem is that when I change an item to on the list, the form continues having the old item.

Does anybody knows **how can I make notice the form that he has to update** it's data with the `ModelView`?

Comment: Is the problem that you don't get updates when modifying *the current list*, or when modifying *an item on the list*?

Comment: I have an array property filled with the data of a List. When I add an Item to that List, nothing happens in the form.

Comment: The first half of Meleak's answer is what you need, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection` and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the ViewModel

**Example**

If you have a List of Persons, make the List an `ObservableCollection<Person>`

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> m_persons;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get
        {
            return m_persons;
        }
        set
        {
            m_persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Persons");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Person`

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string m_name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return m_name;
        }
        set
        {
            m_name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```